# Romance manga about a group of legendary children

Tags: will-yuki-fall-into-hell

So there are 6 (or 7) legendary children. They need to protect the humanity, but one of them is demon (they don't know who it is).

So a girl (the main character) and a boy don't like each other, they are walking home from school and a legendary kid appears and saves them from a weak demon. Then he says he hates that the boy is useless and that he should die and then swears to protect the protagonist.

After that, they all go to a shrine and a priest tells them they're legendary kids and can have powers. One of them starts to punch the idols because he wants power, then you find out the girl is the demon.

The girl has hair that's up at the back of her head. One of the guys has light hair (I don't know what color) and the other guy has black hair and black eyes. This is a romance manga.

Please help me find this manga. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It really sounds like **[Yuki wa Jigoku ni Ochiru no ka](http://myanimelist.net/manga/66509/Yuki_wa_Jigoku_ni_Ochiru_no_ka)** (Fujiwara Hiro)

> The "military history story concerning boys and girls" revolves around
>   Yuki, a girl who has lived in the rural area of Kyoto with her six
>   childhood friends who all share a secret that they cannot tell anyone.
>   On her 16th birthday, Yuki's fate begins to change.

The story begins with the main girl and boy (the one with dark hair), their friends are not present at the beginning, then the light hair boy comes back and argues with the dark hair boy.

Each child has specific kind of the power, and the girl power...

> comes from Hell

[image: Chapter 1 Spead]

Comment: you're welcome, I'm glad that help you